# Php object-oriented-style date comparison

Tags: php, date, comparison

How do you prefer to compare dates when it comes to OOP? What do you think about:

```
$date1 = new Date();
...
$date2 = new Date();

if ($date1 > $date2) {
    ...
}
```

Please do not put in example anything like strtotime etc., only OOP.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to compare, doesn't it?

Comment: Is < defined on DateTime objects?  I suspect that it is not, and this is going to have some very strange behaviour indeed.

Comment: @alexn Yes it does. I want to compare dates.

Comment: @Gian Yes it is. The behavior is not strange at all, on the contrary -- very predictable.

Comment: Then sure, that's the idiomatic way to do this and I'm not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PHP DateTime objects, you can compare dates using the standard comparison operators. For more info and examples, see the [DateTime::diff manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Here is example #2 from the manual:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");

var_dump($date1 == $date2);
var_dump($date1 < $date2);
var_dump($date1 > $date2);
```

Comment: Note that this is only available in PHP 5.2.2+.

Comment: The manuals says PHP 5.3.0, but even that is the [least supported version since more than two years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php#Release_history).

Comment: DateTime::diff returns DateInterval which can't be negative, so I'll never know what date is bigger.

Comment: @Zapadlo: look at the example--you can compare DateTime objects directly using standard PHP comparison operators.

Answer (score 0):

If `Date` should have been the internal `DateTime` class, your code is absolutely fine. But if `Date` is a custom class, the code will not work as expected. Unlike other programming languages PHP does not allow operator overloading which is required for your code to work. You'd need something that tells PHP how it should work with the comparison operators on instances of your class, because PHP cannot know how to compare `$date1` and `$date2` and determine which one is larger.

You could however define some comparison methods on your class...

```
$date1->isLargerThan($date2);
```